# Recursive Programm to print all string combinations of 'a' and 'b' of given length n in c

Tags: c, recursion, permutation, c-strings, function-definition

The task is:

Write a full program that takes an int `n > 0` and recursively prints all combinations of characters 'a' and 'b' on the screen.
Example for n=3: `aaa`, `baa`, `bba`, `aba`, `bab`, `aab`, `abb`, `bbb`.

I assume I have to use something similar to Backtracking.
This is what I have, but Im not able to think of the rest.

```
void rep(int n, char str, int pos) {  //n would be the length and str would be the pointer
    char c[n + 1];
    char d[3];
    d[0] = 'a';
    d[1] = 'b';

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (strlen(c) == n) {    // if c is n long recursion ends
            printf("%s", c);
        } else {
            c[pos] = d[j];       // put 'a' or 'b' in c[pos]
            rep(n, c, pos + 1);  // update pos to next position
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for backtracking. In each string of a’s and b’s, each character is either an a or a b. That should give you an idea about how to represent them. Can you think of anything else in computing where each position has two possibilities? Once you think of such a thing, how do you usually iterate through values of that type?

Comment: Binary. I use the modulo operator,

Answer (score 0):

The variable length array `c` is not initialized

```
char c[n+1]
```

Thus the call of `strlen` in this if statement

```
if(strlen(c) == n){
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover the parameter `str` is not used within the function.

I can suggest the following solution as it is shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void rep( char *s )
{
    puts( s );
    char *p = strchr( s, 'a' );

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        memset( s, 'a', p - s );
        *p = 'b';
        rep( s );
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "aaa";
    rep( s );
}
```

The program output is

```
aaa
baa
aba
bba
aab
bab
abb
bbb
```

That is the function `rep` is initially called with an array that contains a string of the required size `n` (in the demonstration program `n` is equal to `3`) consisting   of all  characters equal to the character `'a'` and recursively outputs all combinations until the string contains all characters equal to the character `'b'`.

Answer (score 0):

There a some issues in your code:

- the `str` argument should have type `char *`
- you so not need new arrays in the recursive function, but use the one the `str` argument points to.
- you do not set a null terminator at the end of your `char` arrays.
- instead of `strlen()`, use `pos` to determine if the recursion should stop.

Here is a modified version

```
#include <stdio.h>

// n is the length and str points to an array of length n+1
void rep(int n, char *str, int pos) {
    if (pos >= n) {
        str[n] = '\0';        // set the null terminator
        printf("%s\n", str);
    } else {
        str[pos] = 'a';
        rep(n, str, pos + 1);
        str[pos] = 'b';
        rep(n, str, pos + 1);
    }
}

#define LEN  3
int main() {
    char array[LEN + 1];
    rep(LEN, array, 0);
    return 0;
}
```